# Play framework 2.7.2 migration, BodyPrasers.parse NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, scala, playframework, akka, play-framework-2.7

Recently i'm trying to upgrade the play version of our application from 2.3.x to 2.7.2. I'm using netty-server for the application to run.

I'm able to make the app up and running.But when I submit simple http GET request, it failing with below error:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lplay/api/mvc/BodyParsers$parse$;]
```

I'd looked for dependency to see any other library is pulling the older version of play but I found none.

```
! @7d519hdfb - Internal server error, for (GET) [/health] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lplay/api/mvc/BodyParsers$parse$;]
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:214)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:144)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler.handle(PlayRequestHandler.scala:91)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler.channelRead(PlayRequestHandler.scala:195)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at com.typesafe.netty.http.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:129)
        at com.typesafe.netty.http.HttpStreamsServerHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsServerHandler.java:96)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:328)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:302)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1421)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:697)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:632)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:549)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lplay/api/mvc/BodyParsers$parse$;
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2049)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3953)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3976)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4960)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4966)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:51)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:155)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:581)
        at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor$1.run(AbstractBindingProcessor.java:176)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.initializeBindings(ProcessedBindingData.java:49)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:122)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:78)
        at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:201)
        at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:156)
        at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:22)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:193)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:185)
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:22)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:185)
        ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lplay/api/mvc/BodyParsers$parse$;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getDeclaredFields(InjectionPoint.java:760)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:670)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:378)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:182)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies(InjectorImpl.java:661)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup(InjectorImpl.java:617)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:603)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:932)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:852)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:291)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:222)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createParameterInjector(InjectorImpl.java:991)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getParametersInjectors(InjectorImpl.java:978)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:69)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:40)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045)
        ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: play.api.mvc.BodyParsers$parse$
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 82 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Make sure play libraries of different versions are not used togathers

Comment: similar issue, the reason was the older play part: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/8807

Comment: @cchantep/andriy-kuba I have tried looking for the older play version in my project dependency:tree and i found none. This error is strange!

Comment: It ought to be a version conflict, no other possible reason

Comment: found this library https://github.com/kenshoo/metrics-play it was pulling older version. Thank u @cc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library https://github.com/kenshoo/metrics-play v2.4.4 & https://github.com/pygmalios/reactiveinflux (has a dependency on play 2.3.10) was being used in our module which was not compatible with new play version 2.7.2. Hence it was throwing above runtime exception.

mvn dependency:tree can help to detect incompatible library when upgrading.